# Get all k-combinations of a n-set lazily

Tags: java, combinations, combinatorics

Given a large 1-d array of numbers. 
In order to save memory for large arrays, I need to get in a loop the next k-combination (C(n,k) in combinatorics), **lazily**.

As the problem is not trivial, I'm having a hard time to implement it.

Here's a pseudo-code of what I am trying to do:

```
public void doSomething(int[] array, int k) {

  for(current combinations in combinations(i, k)) {
     ... // do something
  }
  ...
}
```

**Update:**
Please see the solution below.

Comment: anything you tried so far??

Comment: I've implemented this to get all combinations at once, not using k-pairs. And having hard time calculating it lazily. It's not trivial

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by _"In order to save memory for large arrays..."_, the combinations make the input large regardless of the size of the array--_not_ the length the array.

Comment: @Jared I apply recursive backtracking and need to calculate the next combination lazily, when there's no solution I backtrack early. Thus saving memory

Comment: @vibneiro OK, you say that you need to get the next k-combination of C(n, k).  1) this does not permit a "nice" solution since each computation of the combination goes like the factorial of n and 2) what the hell are you trying to do?  You need to define what n, k, and d mean within your problem.

Comment: The new streaming API in Java 8 is lazy, but without a bit of source code I can't give you a concrete example.

Comment: @Jaren at least this will save GBs of memory for tons of recursive calls. Now, I'm getting OutOfMemory.

Comment: @vibneiro You may be talking about numbers that are computationally _too_ large.  If your input holds 1 million values then the 2-combinations (assuming all 1 million values are distinct) is 499,999,500,000--500 billion is which far above what can be contained in an array.

Comment: I have managed to implement mine. Thanks all, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in C++. What I did was to implement an iterator, which held as its state information the location of the iteration within a systematically generated sequence of combinations. Incrementing the iterator altered the state information to indicate the next combination. Dereferencing the iterator computed the combination at the current position in the sequence.

Comment: Interesting. What is the idea? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the question is given a set of values {x1, x2, x3,...,xn} generate all possible values of {xi, xii, xiii, ..., xk}.  This is a difficult problem to program...however the pattern is pretty easy.  I'm assuming that all {x1, x2, x3,...xn} are distinct (otherwise it's harder).  Assuming that all of the xn are distinct, then there is a very easy pattern to generate all possible k = 2 sets:

```
public class Set{
    private final int[] set;
    public Set(final int ...set){
        this.set = new int[set.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < set.length; ++i)
            this.set[i] = set[i];
    }
}
```

Finding the combinations of the set is simple if you *know* how many combinations you want, here's an example:

```
public int[][] get2Comb(final int[] set){
    int combIndex = 0;
    final int[][] comb = new int[comb2(set.length)][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < set.length - 1; ++i)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < set.length; ++j){
            comb[combIndex][0] = i;
            comnb[combIndex++][1] = j;
        }
    return comb;

}
```

For a k = 3 set it would have to look like this:

```
public int[][] get3Comb(final int[] set){
    int combIndex = 0;
    final int[][] comb = new int[comb3(set.length)][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < set.length - 2; ++i)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < set.length - 1; ++j)
            for(k = j + 1; k < set.length; ++k)
                comb[combIndex][0] = i;
                comb[combIndex][1] = j;
                comnb[combIndex++][2] = k;
            }
    return comb;

}
```

You see that it it obviously recurses...I find it unlikely that there is an iterative scheme (although one technically always exists).  I once faced a problem like this and my solution was to generate code rather than try to figure out the recursive solution (which I suspect should exist).  Java reflection is certainly an idea, but this is basically generating code--so there should be a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented a lazy iterator in Groovy that doesn't require additional memory or preliminary calculation (only array of length k for tracking indices which mostly is of very small length).
You can easily turn one into a java code if you will.

**Lazy Iterator for choosing all C(n, k) combinations:**

```
import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException

class Combinations implements Iterator {

    int[] indices
    def itemset
    def choose
    boolean hasNext = true

    Combinations(def itemset, int choose) {
        this.choose = choose
        this.itemset = itemset

        //Initialize indices
        indices = new int[choose]
        for (i in 0..<choose) {
            indices[i] = i
        }
    }

    private def prepareNext() {
        int rightMostIndex = { /* Closure to find the right-most index */
            for (i in choose-1..0){
                int bounds = itemset.size() - choose + i
                if (indices[i] < bounds) return i
            }
            return -1
        }() // execute closure

        // increment all indices
        if (rightMostIndex >= 0) {
            indices[rightMostIndex]++
            for (i in rightMostIndex+1..<choose) {
                indices[i] = indices[i-1] + 1;
            }
            // there are still more combinations
            hasNext = true
            return
        }
        // reached the end, no more combinations
        hasNext = false
    }

    @Override
    boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNext
    }

    @Override
    def next() {
        if (!hasNext)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        def combination = []

        for (i in 0..<indices.size()) {
            combination << itemset[indices[i]]
        }
        prepareNext()
        return combination
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new NotImplementedException()
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
        def c = new Combinations([1, 2, 3], 2)
        for (e in c) {
            println e
        }
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
```